# XML Load TimeOut

Tags: asp.net, xml, .net-2.0, response-time

I am using below code to load a xml:

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.Load("http://mydomain.com/video/list");
```

in normal situation it works fine, but some times i face a issue of response time out.
sometimes the url from which i wants to load my xml not response me and till that time my application also went timeout.

please tell me what should i do in such situation, so that either i can run my other code if it not responding me within 5 second or any other such solution in which i can do my code in case that url is not responding me xml file.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using a [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) where you have the possibility to set the [TimeOut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout.aspx) for the request. In the case the remote resource doesn't response before this timeout value is reached an exception will be thrown which you could intercept and inform the user.